# Multidimensional associative array of arrays

Tags: php

Why will this not push back or add to the end?

I have tried both methods.

```
class Router
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->routes['GET'] = [];
        $this->routes['POST'] = [];
    }

    public function handle($request)
    {
        echo count($this->routes['GET']) . "<br/>";  // outputs '0'.. why??
    }

    protected function addRoute($methods, $uri, $action)
    {
        #array_push($this->routes['GET'], 'TEST'); // Tried this as well
        $this->routes['GET'][] = 'test';
        echo count($this->routes['GET']) . "<br/>";  // outputs '1'
    }

    private $routes = [];
}
```

After I execute `addRoute` and then check the size of `$this->routes[$methods]` using `count()` in `handle($request)`, it indicates 0.

Comment: What's in `$methods`, how do you call this? where do you `count()`?

Comment: @colburton, fixed.  $methods is of no use here.

Comment: I still can't see any calls to `addRoute()` or `handle()`. You are most likely not using the same object.

Comment: @colburton, see my answer below.  Singleton got me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...

Ahh, the dreaded Singleton got me.  For some reason, the same object was not being used.  I have removed the Singleton pattern from my application.